# Ajax Combobox - SelectedIndex unchaged after deleting

Tags: combobox, selectedindex

Deleting all the text from an ajax combobox doesn't cause the selectedindex to change. If I select item 0 then delete everything, or leave only spaces, it still says item 0 is selected. Is anyone aware of a solution? Besides "dropdownlist", which I regret more and more trying to replace with this terrible, terrible, pretty, but terrible control...

Comment: I also need it to fire the .add_propertyChanged event or whatever the event on the other end of that, not to be picky

Comment: If there's a way to manually call whatever the propertyChanged event is, I can hack the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".formcombobox :input[type=text]").each(function (i) {
  this.onblur = function () {
    var comboBox = $find(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id); // the combobox
    if (jQuery.trim(comboBox.get_textBoxControl().value) == "") { // if textbox is empty
      comboBox.set_selectedIndex(-1);                             // then set selected index to -1                       
    }
  }
});
```

Assuming the combobox has class="formcombobox", this attaches an onblur event to the textbox, and the set_selectedIndex() function triggers the change event, so this will correct the index when the user *leaves* a blank value and allow me to handle the change

I feel like there's probably a better way to get the parent but, whatever. It's good enough for me

I wonder if having a legitimate blank option would've went differently...